# update is inserting 0's or nulls for float field when subquery does not match

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a field that is a mixture of nulls and float values (or I have tried making the default value 0 instead of null) that I'm updating. If a row does not match, it updates it to null. What am I missing?

```
UPDATE table1 t1 set field1 = 
(SELECT t2.field1 from table2 t2 
 WHERE t2.some_field = t1.some_filed and 
 t2.some_other_field = foo)
```

However any rows that do not match:

```
 WHERE t2.some_field = t1.some_field
```

MySQL puts in a null value (or zero). These two tables do not have an equal number of fields so I just want to update a few fields and not overwrite anything it does not match in the update statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try with an `INNER JOIN` query

```
UPDATE table1 t1 
INNER JOIN table2 t2 
ON t2.some_field = t1.some_filed
SET t1.field1 = t2.field1 
WHERE t2.some_other_field = 'foo'
```

Comment: Yes! that works, but would you mind explaining why? And why my method did not?

Comment: @jwillis You were not joining the tables, but just selecting data from the other table on a where clause, this might have caused the wrong return. Joining table will make database selecting only values that mach given relation, so there will be no errors. You can have a visual explanation of join query [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.codinghorror.com%2Fblog%2F2007%2F10%2Fa-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html&ei=dHe5UexBh4PgBLK7gfgN&usg=AFQjCNHWPzRGaG2Vr4qBugi6LTKy_t-ygw&bvm=bv.47883778,d.bGE)

Comment: @jwillis i was also checking your query, you were missing quote around your values 'foo', this might cause the error too because it is a string and not an integer, so you will always need to surround with quotes when using strings